# Как Java программе получить разрешение на удаление файла в Windows?

Tags: java, zip, permissions

Разработал небольшую программу, которая из zip архива распаковывает файл, затем копирует по нужному мне пути и вставляет, после чего, по логике, этот файл нужно удалить. В Ubuntu работает без проблем, но на Windows не получается.

> System.out.println(file1.delete());

Возвращается false. При этом файл успешно копируется, значит проблема не в пути к файлу.

Comment: Если файл существует, и это именно файл, а не директория, то Java программе не хватает прав. Попробуй запустить консоль и программу или сразу саму программу из-под администратора.

Answer (score 0):

В try catch оберни.
Булевский false совершенно ни о чем не говорит.